# Comparar un string entre un rango de numeros en JavaScript

Tags: javascript

**Hola a todos. Lo que estoy intentando realizar es validar un objeto que este entre un rango de numeros**

Bueno lo que estoy tratando de hacer es comparar un objeto que este entre un rango de numeros como el siguiente codigo que muestra.

```js
const data = [  
     {  id: 843, hora_ingreso: '11:44:56 AM', hora_salida:'11:47:57 AM',},
    ,{  id: 845, hora_ingreso: '8:01:32 PM',hora_salida: ''}
    ,{  id: 846, hora_ingreso: '9:11:20 PM',hora_salida: '12:13:51 PM',}
    ,{  id: 847, hora_ingreso: '10:13:35 PM',hora_salida: '12:13:45 PM',}
    ,{  id: 848, hora_ingreso: '11:48:13 PM',hora_salida: '12:48:20 PM',}
    ,{  id: 848, hora_ingreso: '2:48:13 PM',hora_salida: '12:48:20 PM',}
    ,{  id: 848, hora_ingreso: '1:48:13 PM',hora_salida: '12:48:20 PM',}
    ,{  id: 848, hora_ingreso: '3:48:13 PM',hora_salida: '12:48:20 PM',}
    ,{  id: 846, hora_ingreso: '9:55:20 PM',hora_salida: '12:13:51 PM',}


];

// aqui quiero insertar un metodo que pueda retornarme los valores de
// data.hora_ingreso >= 8 &&   data.hora_ingreso =< 12 
  
// El Objeto deberia de retornarme entre  data.hora_ingreso >= 8, 9, 10, 11, 12

/*
  lo que quisiera que me retorne es :
  
     {  id: 843, hora_ingreso: '11:44:56 AM', hora_salida:'11:47:57 AM',},
    ,{  id: 845, hora_ingreso: '8:01:32 PM',hora_salida: ''}
    ,{  id: 846, hora_ingreso: '9:11:20 PM',hora_salida: '12:13:51 PM',}
    ,{  id: 847, hora_ingreso: '10:13:35 PM',hora_salida: '12:13:45 PM',}
    ,{  id: 848, hora_ingreso: '11:48:13 PM',hora_salida: '12:48:20 PM',}
    ,{  id: 846, hora_ingreso: '9:55:20 PM',hora_salida: '12:13:51 PM',}
    

*/

let date = data.filter( e => e.hora_ingreso >= '8');

console.log( date );
```

*Intente hacer entre hora_ingreso >= '8' && hora_ingreso <= '12' pero al llegar a 12 filtra los demas numeros como ejemplo 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12 y de esta manera la validación pierde sentido*

Comment: Independiente del formato ¿por qué buscas comparar solo una parte de la marca tiempo?, eso te generaría eventualmente inconsistencias, considera que puede ser mas prudente considerar horas-minutos y segundos

Comment: Incluso no sería mejor parsear los datos directamente a Date y compararlas con `<` `>`?

Comment: Si pero alguna solución de ejemplo por favor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una solución sería hacer un split al valor de `hora_ingreso` y tomar el primer elemento del arreglo y compararlo.

```
// ejemplo de split()
// let hora = '11:44:56 AM'
// hora.split(':') producirá un arreglo igual a ['11','44','56 AM']
// la hora está en la primera posición del arreglo [0]

let date = data.filter( e =>
           {
              // usar split() para separar la cadena de la hora
              // y tomar el primer elemento del arreglo
              let hora = e.hora_ingreso.split(':')[0];
              // retornar la validación de la hora
              return hora >= 8 && hora <= 12
           } 
   );
```

Comment: Mil gracias me funciono .

Answer (score 0):

Creo que lo mejor sería utilizar un formato de hora completo con todo y fecha para así poder parsear usando `Date`. Pero en caso de que no tengas control sobre el origen de los datos te recomiendo usar `momentjs` y parsear las fechas con el formato que necesitas.

```
var moment = require('moment'); 

const hora1 = moment('2:48:13 PM', 'hh:mm:ss A');

const hora2 = moment('8:48:13 AM', 'hh:mm:ss A');

console.log(hora1<hora2?"hora1 ocurrió antes que hora2":"hora2 ocurrió antes que hora1");
```

Resultado:

```
hora2 ocurrió antes que hora1
```

Ya con este parseo puedes hacer cosas como:

```
const ref9am = moment('9:00:00 AM', 'hh:mm:ss A');

console.log(`Hora1 ${hora1>ref9am ? "ocurrió" : "no ocurrió"} antes de las 9am`);

console.log(`Hora2 ${hora2>ref9am ? "ocurrió" : "no ocurrió"} antes de las 9am`);
```

Resultado:

```
Hora1 ocurrió antes de las 9am
Hora2 no ocurrió antes de las 9am
```